# Spark: generate an error when reading from folder without _SUCCESS file

Tags: apache-spark, exception

I cannot seem to find any documentation, but I want to understand how I can do the following:

- We have Spark pipelines that *write* data to S3 in the standard format where they write several `part-...` files and the `_SUCCESS` file to the folder.
- We then have further Spark pipelines that *read* data from those S3 buckets.
- We would like to have the pipelines automatically throw an exception (fail) if they try to read from a folder that *does not have* the `_SUCCESS` file.
- We can create some sort of user-created function to manage this test, but it seems so common that I figured there must be an easy Spark-native way to generate this exception if the file is not found.

Is there such a native Spark way to trigger that exception?

Comment: Using Delta or Apache Iceberg will protect against these kinds of partial writes.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of is using ,

```
boolean isExists=getFileSystem(spark.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration())).exists(new Path("location of _SUCCESS file"));
```

if this returns false throw an exception.

Comment: Right, so just test for the file's existence.  I have a weird corner case where I am copying from one location to another, the problem is that the `_SUCCESS` file is also being copied, whether or not the copy completes.  There are plenty of work arounds... I was just hoping to use something Spark-native.

Comment: not sure we have a spark native way of checking file existence, not that I knew of.
Can your copy be more specific to only copy files that start with part-*.

Comment: Thanks @Neethu .  Yes, it can.  As I said, there are workarounds.  But I prefer choosing the cleanest options that are closest to the API.  I just figured that there must be a Spark exception for what I was describing.